# ADBannerView delegate methods never triggering

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, delegates, iad

Question is as simple as the tip of the question.

banner is working in test mode in device.
(seems like so: "You re connected to the iAd Network").

declared `-didFailToReceiveAdWithError`, `-bannerViewDidLoadAd` and `-bannerViewActionShouldBegin`.
and ADBannverView1.delegate assigned to self (is a cocos2d CCLayer)

but these methods never called. I drop some breakpoints that never runs into.

have you any idea ?

---

Question 2: 
what is the difference between these property definations ? should I use weak, assign ? or IBOutlet is a necessarry ?
I tried all 3 combination and all worked.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) ADBannerView *iAdView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *iAdView;
@property(nonatomic,assign) ADBannerView *iAdView;
```

Comment: Did you make 'self' follow the AdBannerViewDelegate protocol?

Comment: sorry.
I put wrong named ivar, was 
ADBannerView *iaDView;
and property was iadView so naming mistake made dublicated and wrongly assigned+syncronized property.
after correcting name.all worked fine.

Comment: add ADBannerViewDelegate to the interface and assign adBannerView.delegate=self; after adbannerview allocation it hits breakpoint for me

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I also had this line in my code `self.canDisplayBannerAds=YES;`

After I removed it delegate method were called properly.